# Tensorflow docker image not using GPU for inference/predictions

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, tensorflow, nvidia-docker

**My requirement:**

Make the inference task run on GPU for object detection using tensorflow.

**Current status**:

I am using AWS GPU instance (p2.xlarge) for training as well as for inference.
The training part runs well on GPU. No problem here. (Graphics card: Tesla M60)

For getting predictions, I have created a flask server encapsulating the tensorflow detection with some additional logic to it. I am going to deploy this service (Flask + tensorflow) as a docker container. The base image that I am using is `tensorflow/tensorflow:1.12.0-gpu-py3`. My `dockerfile` looks something like this:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.12.0-gpu-py3
COPY ./app /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app
RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt
RUN mkdir /app/venv
WORKDIR /app
RUN export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/app/main.py"]
ENV LISTEN_PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080
```

I am able to deploy this by:

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia --gpus all --name <my-long-img-name> 
-v <somepath>:<anotherpath> -p 8080:8080 -d <my-long-img-name>
```

and successfully make calls to the endpoints on port 8080 from postman.

Basically, what I mean is all the drivers are setup properly.

One of the endpoint in flask is like: (For testing if GPU is being used or not)

```
@app.route("/testgpu", methods=["GET"])
def testgpu():
    import tensorflow as tf
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
        b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
        c = tf.matmul(a, b)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print (sess.run(c))
```

When I call this endpoint I get no errors (If there was no gpu detected it would throw error). This means gpu is detected for this snippet. YAY !!

I also added these 2 lines to my main code execution flow:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

and it outputs:

```
Local devices : 
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 17661279486087266140
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 9205152708262911170
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 3134142118233627849
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 7447009690
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 6613138223738633761
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Tesla M60, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 5.2"
]
```

YAY again, the GPU is detected.

Even the logs from tensorflow is taking GPU.

```
2019-11-18 08:45:29.944580: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-11-18 08:45:29.944603: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2019-11-18 08:45:29.944611: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N 
2019-11-18 08:45:29.944721: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7101 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla M60, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 5.2)
```

Everything seems smooth here, but the main part where GPU should be running is not taking it. It is using CPU. There is this another endpoint (let's say, `/getpredictions`) along with `/testgpu` that is mentioned above which runs the detection and returns the output.

**The problem:**
Whenever I call `/getpredictions` from postman on port 8080 instead of using GPU it takes CPU and returns the output in around ~30+ seconds.

Is there anything missing here? Any workarounds?

Let me know if I need to add some more information to the question.

Comment: Would be useful to see flask code which handles the `getpredictions/` endpoint.

Comment: @v25 that endpoint takes in a file and runs the inference on that file, then returns the output. This endpoint runs `run_inference_for_single_image` method from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb <- this link. For some specific reason I cannot share the exact code. But, it's more over the same.

Comment: That method from the linked code doesn't specify `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):` like your `testgpu()` method so I'd check that's in your `getpredictions/` route.  Maybe this is a no-brainer though :-) had to say without seeing that code.

Comment: @v25 I tried including `tf.device('/gpu:0'):` there too. Actually in multiple places, but could not get it to run on GPU. Also, TensorFlow takes GPU as default (if Cuda drivers are properly configured) I believe.

Comment: How are you identifying that the gpu isn't being used?  Just the latency is bad or are you profiling the gpu?  I wonder if it could be adding lots of extra latency as it loads the model.  You could try multiple predictions on the same image and time them.  Generally the first prediction takes extra long as in this link: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/33510059/53273394-e7f9b300-36c1-11e9-9ab4-ebe4c3556be4.png It will vary based on what model you are using.

Comment: @shortcipher3 I can be sure that the GPU is not under load. It shows 0% load when using `nvidia-smi` but the memory is almost full. The model in my case is preloaded in order to reduce the extra latency (reduced the predictions by ~5+ secs). And yeap, the first prediction takes time (~15secs for 100kb sized image) and after that it takes (~5secs for 100kb sized image). Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm concerned about the memory being almost full.  You might try a different gpu, just to see although it doesn't look like the p3 has much more memory.  You might also try to see what is filling up the memory.  I've had jobs that use different frameworks on the same gpu: mxnet, caffe, and tensorflow and I found out that tensorflow was eating up gpu memory causing one of my other models to crash.  I was able to restrict how much gpu memory tensorflow was allowed to use which solved that particular problem.  Good luck!

Comment: @shortcipher3 I have 7 models pre-loaded. I think that's the reason for the memory to be almost full. No crashing for force close happens in my case. But sure, I will look into this memory part down the road. Thanks for the suggestion. Currently, I am more concerned about the GPU process utilization.

Answer (score 2):

from the docs you should add gpu option when running container
like this:

`docker run -it --gpus all -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter`